# Use composite key as foreign key in table SQL Server when we only need to reference 1 element of the key

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, composite-key

I have a doubt about how to reference as a foreign key in a table when the key is composited but I only need 1 part of the key.

Example (Tables 'Languages' and 'Countries' have no problem, The doubt is in the 'Flags' Table):

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Languages](
        [Id_Language] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Language] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Languages] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id_Language]))
```

---

- 1   -  English
- 2   -  Spanish
- 3   -  French
- 4   -  German

  ---

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Countries](
        [Id_Country] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Id_Language] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Country] [nvarchar](80) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Countries] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id_Country], [Id_Language])
     FOREIGN KEY([Id_Language]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Languages] ([Id_Language]))
```

---

- 1   -   1   -   United States
- 1   -   2   -   Estados Unidos
- 1   -   3   -   États Unis
- 2   -   1   -   Spain
- 2   -   2   -   España
- 2   -   3   -   Spagne

  ---

And HERE finally is the doubt (Because the picture of the flag is per country and but not depending on the language)

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Flags](
        [Id_Flag] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Id_Country] [int] NOT NULL, ------ HOW CAN I DO IT?????????????
        [Image] [image] NOT NULL
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Flags] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id_Flag]))
```

The result should be:

---

- 1   -  1  -  (https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/wikipedia/flags/16/US-United-States-Flag-icon.png)
- 2   -  2  -  (https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/wikipedia/flags/16/ES-Spain-Flag-icon.png)
- 3   -  3  -  (https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/wikipedia/flags/16/FR-France-Flag-icon.png)

  ---

I hope you can help me with this.

EDIT: Sorry if I could not explain well. 
The table Countries contains 'countries' but with the corresponding translation for each language, so, it doesn't depend on which language speaks each country is just the same country name in different languages.

And then 'flags' should be unique per country without dependence of which language we're referring to.

I hope this helps as clarification.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your model represents actual entities. The names should CLEARLY identify what entity they represent. A country is NOT identified by any particular language if you are modeling actual political entities. Here you seem to confuse the political entity with the primary or official language of that country since you include it in the primary key. Something is wrong - but the correction requires knowledge of your actual model.

Comment: And why would "flag" be a separate entity? I'm fairly certain that there are no official counties that "share" a flag. But maybe you have a different model / goal in mind?

Comment: So Canada can't be a country because the official languages are English and French.

Comment: EDIT: Sorry if I could not explain well. The table Countries contains 'countries' but with the corresponding translation for each language, so, it doesn't depend on which language speaks each country is just the same country name in different languages.

And then 'flags' should be unique per country without dependence of which language we're referring to.

I hope this helps as clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You are assigning attributes to entities they don't belong to. See the diagram below.

This is how your sample model might look like:
[image: Countries and their languages]

Some details are below:

1. Your `Languages` table is fine.
2. Identifier of a country should not include language. It should be a single field, as countries tend not to depend on any other entities.
3. Generally, every country tends to have a single flag. You can move the actual picture into a separate table, linked 1:1 to `dbo.Countries`, or you can include the data into the country directly, as on the sample model.
4. Don't use `image` or other similar data types in new development, they have been deprecated for 15 years already.
5. List of official languages depend on `country + language` combination.
6. The `dbo.Country` table has alternative key (marked `<ak>` on the diagram) on the `EnglishName` column (because you need some way to distinguish countries from each other without resorting to the `dbo.CountryLanguages` table). This approach is disputable; if you don't like to hardcode any kind of language here, you can use some other natural key for a country. Off the top of the head, [ISO 3166](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) codes might be a good choice.

Here is the DDL for the model, to make it easier to understand:

```sql
/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: Countries                                             */
/*==============================================================*/
create table dbo.[Countries] (
   [Id] int                  identity(1,1),
   [EnglishName] varchar(100)         not null,
   [FlagImage] varbinary(max)       not null,
   constraint [PK_Countries] primary key (Id),
   constraint [UQ_Countries_EnglishName] unique (EnglishName)
)
go

execute sp_addextendedproperty 'MS_Description', 
   'Country identifier',
   'schema', 'dbo', 'table', 'Countries', 'column', 'Id'
go

execute sp_addextendedproperty 'MS_Description', 
   'Country name in English',
   'schema', 'dbo', 'table', 'Countries', 'column', 'EnglishName'
go

execute sp_addextendedproperty 'MS_Description', 
   'Country flag image',
   'schema', 'dbo', 'table', 'Countries', 'column', 'FlagImage'
go

/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: CountryLanguages                                      */
/*==============================================================*/
create table dbo.[CountryLanguages] (
   [CountryId] int                  not null,
   [LanguageId] int                  not null,
   [CountryName] nvarchar(100)        not null,
   constraint [PK_CountryLanguages] primary key (CountryId, LanguageId)
)
go

execute sp_addextendedproperty 'MS_Description', 
   'Country identifier',
   'schema', 'dbo', 'table', 'CountryLanguages', 'column', 'CountryId'
go

execute sp_addextendedproperty 'MS_Description', 
   'Language identifier',
   'schema', 'dbo', 'table', 'CountryLanguages', 'column', 'LanguageId'
go

execute sp_addextendedproperty 'MS_Description', 
   'Name of the country in that language',
   'schema', 'dbo', 'table', 'CountryLanguages', 'column', 'CountryName'
go

/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: Languages                                             */
/*==============================================================*/
create table dbo.[Languages] (
   [Id] int                  identity(1,1),
   [Name] nvarchar(100)        not null,
   constraint [PK_Languages] primary key (Id)
)
go

execute sp_addextendedproperty 'MS_Description', 
   'Language identifier',
   'schema', 'dbo', 'table', 'Languages', 'column', 'Id'
go

execute sp_addextendedproperty 'MS_Description', 
   'Language name',
   'schema', 'dbo', 'table', 'Languages', 'column', 'Name'
go

alter table dbo.CountryLanguages
   add constraint FK_CountryLanguages_Countries_CountryId foreign key (CountryId)
      references dbo.Countries (Id)
go

alter table dbo.CountryLanguages
   add constraint FK_CountryLanguages_Languages_LanguageId foreign key (LanguageId)
      references dbo.Languages (Id)
go
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Roger, This sound interesting. I've never used before the AK so I'm going to take a look if this could fit in my Schema.

Comment: Regarding the Image type is not a problem I'm using as a reference a very old database to create the new structure but I will change to the new type.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want the flags table to refer to the Countries table? If you alter the table by adding a foreign key constraint, this means a valid country would need to be supplied when inserting/updating data into the flags table.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Flags
ADD CONSTRAINT [fk_constraint_name] FOREIGN KEY (Id_Country)
REFERENCES dbo.Countries (ID_Country)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @KMoe. That was the idea but I cannot do that because Countries' key is not just Id_Country, instead is Id_Country + Id_Language. So, when I try to add the FK as you mentioned I receive an error because need to include Id_Language too.